# django form wizard - define form_list and condition_dict in views.py (WizardView subclass), NOT in urls.py

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-formwizard

today I've started using Form Wizard in django 1.4. The functionality seems to be nice, but according to the documentation, one need to pass the `form_list` (and `condition_dict`, when necessary) to the `as_view` method (which means `urls.py`) instead of providing it in the subclass of `WizardView`

This means writing some logics within `urls.py` and not `views.py` which I believe is against django pattern, as the views module is supposed to be responsible for views logics.

I've ended up with following:

```
# views.py
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    _form_list = (
        ('init', forms.MyWizardFormInit), 
        ('newuser', forms.MyWizardFormNewUser),
    )
    _condition_dict = {
        'newuser': lambda wizard: (wizard.get_cleaned_data_for_step('init') or {}).get('existing_user') == 'False'
    }
```

and the `urls.py`:

```
url(.., MyWizard.as_view(MyWizard._form_list, condition_dict = MyWizard._condition_dict)),
```

which really looks *silly* and *ridiculous*.
Is there any correct way to **prevent declaring logics in urls.py** while **keeping DRY** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly cleaner version might look like this:

**views.py**

```
my_wizard_view = MyWizard.as_view(MyWizard._form_list, condition_dict=MyWizard._condition_dict))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^my_wizard/$', my_wizard_view, name='my_wizard')
```

Comment: it still doesn't look as good as "normal" CBVs but is a bit better ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WizardWiev yet, but have you tried setting those attributes on the WizardView subclass itself instead of passing them through the url definition? Or, filing that, have you tried overloading the `WizardView.get_form` method?

Comment: these are View attrributes, not form attributes (BTW, for form attributes there's get_form_kwargs). The problem is that one can't set that on subclass of WizardView as it causes lots of strange errors, and - according to django docs - the proper way is to pass it through url config. Again, it applies ONLY to the WizardView, and breaks the "standard" behavior of CBVs. That is why I asked that question ;)